# How to set an option to blank if hidden, but keep default if visible - html/php?

Tags: php, html

I've got a select field and it defaults to one option (A in the below code).  But when it is hidden, I'd like the value set to none of the select values (' ' in my case).  At present, it defaults to A.  How do I get it to default to ' ' (spaces)?

```
<div class="form-group row" <?php if (showoption==0) {?>style="display: none;"<?php }?>>
  <div class="floating">
  <label for="options">Options<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="options" name="options">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="OptionA" selected>A</option>
    <option value="OptionB">B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is denoted by the `selected` attribute. Simply swap this to the relevant `<option>`.

As for hiding it only when the option is hidden, you can use the same sort of PHP logic to `echo` it at the relevant point. `echo` `selected` for `''` when the conditional is `true`, `A` when it is false:

```
<div class="form-group row" <?php if (showoption==0) {?>style="display: none;"<?php }?>>
  <div class="floating">
  <label for="options">Options<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="options" name="options">
    <option value="" <?php if (showoption == 0) { echo "selected"; } ?>Please select</option>
    <option value="OptionA" <?php if (showoption != 0) { echo "selected"; } ?>>A</option>
    <option value="OptionB">B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```